# Spring Boot Password Encoding

Tags: spring, hash, passwords, encode, bcrypt

I am new to Spring boot and I am trying to configure the security for my api. I am using PasswordEncoding:

```
public static String encodePassword(String plainPassword){
    BCryptPasswordEncoder bCryptPasswordEncoder=new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    return bCryptPasswordEncoder.encode(plainPassword);
}
```

In the SecurityConfig class I got the following method:

```
@Bean
public PasswordEncoder getPasswordEncoder(){
    return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
}
```

But each time  given the same input the output is always different, can someone explain to me the reason behind this and how I can possibly fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is by design, there's nothing for you to "fix".  The reason is because the BCrypt algorithm includes a salt, which will be different every time you call it.  What this means is that if you're trying to encode a plain-text password to a hash and compare it to another hash, it's not going to match.  You can, however, use the method, `matches`, in `BCryptPasswordEncoder` to compare.

Here's a test that demonstrates this

```
@Test
public void encodeAndMatch() {
    BCryptPasswordEncoder bc = new BCryptPasswordEncoder();

    String p1 = bc.encode("password");
    String p2 = bc.encode("password");
    String p3 = bc.encode("password");
    
    assertNotEquals(p1, p2);
    assertNotEquals(p1, p3);
    assertNotEquals(p2, p3);

    assertTrue(bc.matches("password", p1));
    assertTrue(bc.matches("password", p2));
    assertTrue(bc.matches("password", p3));
}
```

Here you can see that the same password generated three distinct hashes, but the encoder can still compare the original plain-text password to each of them and match.